# beautifulSoup find_all() with series of tags

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I am looking to search a website for specific tags within tags with bs find_all(). for example, searching for data within:

```
<li class='x'>
    <small class='y'>
```

I am currently using this code to search but am coming up with extra results from elsewhere on the html page because I haven't specified that I only want to search within li tags with class x.

```
labels = [element.text for element in soup.find_all('small', {'class':'label'})]
```

how do I specify specifically where I want to search?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify like this:

```
optionA = [element.text for element in soup.find('ul').find_all('small', {'class':'label'})]
```

Will first find the parent `<ul>` and than all `<small>`

```
optionB = [element.text for element in soup.select('ul small.label')]
```

Alternativ, use the css selectors, in my opinion much better for chaining tags and classes.

**Example**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''<ul>
  <li><small class="label">Coffee</small></li>
  <li><small class="label">Tea</small></li>
  <li><small class="label">Milk</small></li>
</ul>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html,)

optionA = [element.text for element in soup.find('ul').find_all('small', {'class':'label'})]
optionB = [element.text for element in soup.select('ul small.label')]

print(optionA)
print(optionB)
```

**Output**

```
['Coffee', 'Tea', 'Milk']
['Coffee', 'Tea', 'Milk']
```

Comment: can option b work when the attribute has a space in it? for example td.table__cell u-semi I think is recognized as multiple tags as there is a space.

Comment: Yes, it can - Just chain the classes with `.` -> `td.table__cell.u-semi` | Take a look at: [css selectors in bs4](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.select()` to apply css-selectors that allow more advanced searching:

```
 soup.select('.label>small')
```

This will find a element with tag `small` with the immediate parent having a class `label`. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors for examples of more CSS selectors, though note Beautiful Soup may not support some of the newer syntax.